How to create manually a KSP container object in "SafeNet Key Storage Provider"
I've a Windows PKI system running with Luna Network HSM 7 and need to use a certificate which
its private key resides in the HSM and not exportable by design of the system. This cert was generated with a different account which has already decommissioned on the same server.
So I have a certificate which has lost its private key linkage in my account and have to bind its private key to it.
In order to do this I should create manually a KSP container object in "SafeNet Key Storage Provider". I know the private and public key
handles from HSM and just need a utility or command to achieve this like Amazon Cloud HSM in the folowing method:
C:\Program Files\Amazon\CloudHSM>import_key.exe -from HSM -privateKeyHandle <private key handle> -publicKeyHandle <public key handle>
This issue looks like the below question but our HSM is Thales Luna Network HSM 7:
Windows doesn't create assign "Key Container" when adding cert tied to Cavium (AWS CloudHSMv2)
Do you know such a command or utility to create a KSP container object manually in Thales "SafeNet Key Storage Provider" on Windows Server?

does your key exist and accessible in HSM?

yes, key in the HSM and accessible.

have you tried to run certutil -repairstore my <CertSerial> or certutil -user -repairstore my <CertSerial>?

yes, returning "Missing stored keyset"

================ Certificate 2 ================
Serial Number:
Issuer:
NotBefore: 7/26/2022 10:39 PM
NotAfter: 7/26/2024 10:49 PM
Subject:
Non-root Certificate
Template:
Cert Hash(sha1):
No key provider information
Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption.
CertUtil: -store command completed successfully.

Can you recomission the old server?  If so, you need to run ksputil.exe c /s <n> /n <name of key> /t <fqdn of new server> on the original server to allow it to be visible in KSP on the new server.

sorry my bad (updated the original question), the server is same, admin accounts are different, so this cert was generated with an account already decommissioned, I can't access the old account. But I can't see its private key from my account.

Have you checked/compared case sensitivity between the actual (new) account name and the account name added in kspconfig.exe? I've seen instances where they differ and the key is therefore inaccessible.  Long shot, but worth a check.

I checked it now, the actual account name is correct in the kspconfig.exe.

Presumably, you can see the objects with cmu.exe list?

yes, I can see all objects.
